# Incorrect number on count

Tags: mysql

I have a table to count comments and likes one user has:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cda66/1

Have 3 likes and 6 comments. BUT it shows 3 likes and 18 comments. It is always multiplying. 3 x 6 = 18 and it is wrong.

how to solve this?

```
select 

count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count,
SUM(CASE comentarios.delete WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as comentarios_count 

from posts p

left join likes on likes.post = p.id
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id

group by p.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `count(distinct)` on the commentaries if you put the condition in the `left join` clause

```
select count(distinct l.user) as likes_count,
       count(distinct c.id) as comentarios_count     
from posts p    
left join likes l on l.post = p.id
left join comentarios c on c.foto = p.id
                       and c.delete = 0    
group by p.id
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cda66/14)

Comment: The join multiplies the results and if you don't use `distinct` the count is off

Comment: @jurgen I accept that that is what the OPs query is doing but does that mean the last join in the ops query is to the result set of from posts p    
left join likes l on l.post = p.id and if so why?

Comment: @P.Salmon: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are asking.